# ¿Cómo depurar una librería dentro de un proyecto?

Tags: java, eclipse, depuración

Me descargue eclipse hace poco y todavía no se bien como funciona. Tengo un proyecto en java, en el que he agregado una librería, que he creado yo mismo. Y lo que quiero hacer es depurar/debugear esa librería funcionando en mi proyecto, pero no se como hacerlo. Desde NetBeans me lo hacia automáticamente, siempre y cuando tuviese el proyecto de la librería abierto junto con el proyecto de mi programa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habia que ir a las propiedas del proyecto, en la categoria libraries, va a aparecer un apartado classpath, ahi van a salir las librerías que hay en el proyecto, haces click en la flecha que sale al lado de la libreria que necesitas, y te van a salir varias categorías, haces click en la que dice Source attachment, te va a salir el explorador de archivos, ahí buscas el proyecto de tu librería y lo añadís, y listo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]